# How can I save a downloaded file with Capacitor in Ionic4 Angular?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I have recently published my Ionic 4 Angular App both as web app and as native Android app.

 In the native Android app, everything works fine, except saving a downloaded file.

To download and save a file, I've always used `file-saver` npm package as follows (this is a shared service that I invoke every time I have to download something, from a PDF to an image, etc...):

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

// ...

saveGenericFile(api: string, fileinfos: any, idFile: string): any {
    let mediaType = 'application/pdf';
    let fileName = '';

    if (fileinfos != null) {
      mediaType = fileinfos.contentType;
      fileName = fileinfos.fileName;
    }

    const headers = this.base.commonHeader;
    const url = this.baseUrl + api + '?id=' + idFile;
    this.http.post(url, null, { headers, responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-const
        let blob = new Blob([response], { type: mediaType });
        saveAs(blob, fileName);
      }, e => {
        console.error(e);
        this.toastsvc.generateToast('ERROR! An error occurred while saving this File, try later or contact support', 'danger');
      }, () => {
        /* do nothing */
      }
    );
  }
```

As I said above, this code snippet works fine, but just when I have to save something from the web release.

The only online examples I was able to find were all about Cordova and/or previous/deprecated versions.

About Capacitor, I just found [this documentation](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/filesystem/) and from that I just found this code snippet:

```
import { Plugins, FilesystemDirectory, FilesystemEncoding } from '@capacitor/core';

const { Filesystem } = Plugins;

fileWrite() {
  try {
    Filesystem.writeFile({
      path: 'secrets/text.txt',
      data: "This is a test",
      directory: FilesystemDirectory.Documents,
      encoding: FilesystemEncoding.UTF8
    });
  } catch(e) {
    console.error('Unable to write file', e);
  }
}
```

But the issue is that my function above returns a blob and this one only accept a string for data.

So, **is there any Capacitor-Native equivalent feature that I can use to download (and save) Blob files both when running as web-app and when running as Android native app?**

---

**UPDATE**

I've also tried the following, but it's not working:

```
saveGenericFile(api: string, fileinfos: any, gidFile: string): any {
    let mediaType = 'application/pdf';
    let fileName = '';

    if (fileinfos != null) {
      mediaType = fileinfos.contentType;
      fileName = fileinfos.fileName;
    }

    const headers = this.base.commonHeader;
    const url = this.baseUrl + api + '?id=' + gidFile;
    this.http.post(url, null, { headers, responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        if (!this.useCordovaDl) {
          // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-const
          let blob = new Blob([response], { type: mediaType });
          saveAs(blob, fileName);
        } else {
          this.blobFileWrite(fileName, response);
        }
      }, e => {
        console.error(e);
        this.toastsvc.generateToast('ERROR! An error occurred while saving this File, try later or contact support', 'danger');
      }, () => {
        /* do nothing */
      }
    );
  }

  blobFileWrite(filename: string, blobfile: Blob) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    // This fires after the blob has been read/loaded.
    reader.addEventListener('loadend', (e: any) => {
      const text = e.srcElement.result;
      this.fileWrite(filename, text);
    });

    // Start reading the blob as text.
    reader.readAsText(blobfile);
  }

  fileWrite(filename: string, filedata: string) {
    try {
      Filesystem.writeFile({
        path: filename,
        data: filedata
        // ,
        // directory: FilesystemDirectory.Documents,
        // encoding: FilesystemEncoding.UTF8
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Unable to write file', e);
    }
  }
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

It looks like [there's still an opened issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/974) about saving Blob data with Capacitor. I will look for a Cordova solution in the meanwhile. Or, I will simply disable every download button if platform is android or ios.

 I will post every working Cordova Workaround down here, if I'll be able to find one

Comment: using FileReader works, unless you you have cordova-plugin-file installed an use angular, because angular's zonejs causes a bug that prevents FileReader from working

Comment: @jcesarmobile Hi, thanks for your comment! Actually, I'm using Ionic 4 with Angular 7, so this may explain why FileReader isn't working. Is there any github issue about this?

Comment: yes https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1564, see last comment, it has a link with a workaround

Comment: just wanted to chime in here and say that the capacitor-community HTTP plugin does file downloads: https://github.com/capacitor-community/http

Comment: Hi @ingage, thanks for your comment! Didn't know about that repo, I will certainly give a try

Answer (score 3):

if what you want to achieve is save the file in the filesystem, you can save it with string base64 to filesystem

```
image = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo... bla bla bla"
Capacitor.Plugins.Filesystem.appendFile({
    data:image,
    path:"directory/image.png",
    directory:"DOCUMENTS"
}).then(c=>{console.log("se escribiooo")})
```

its result in image in your filesystem (i just tried this code in the android emulator), just use the method appendFile instead writeFile, and base64 instead blob, if you only have the blob you just have to convert it to base64

Answer (score 2):

Sharing my workaround with you.

I'm using web-implementation of the Filesystem plugin.
Don't know if it's a good solution but it helps solving my problem.

```
import { FilesystemDirectory, FilesystemEncoding } from '@capacitor/core'
// const { Filesystem } = Plugins // => Doesn't work with blob in native
// Workaround: Use Web-Implementation of plugin
import { FilesystemPluginWeb } from '@capacitor/core/dist/esm/web/filesystem.js'
const Filesystem = new FilesystemPluginWeb()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a plugin, to which you can pass a URL and it will download natively. As you have already discovered passing blob/file is not possible, yet.

If there's no plugin available or you don't want to create one.
You can invoke the native function from `js` which you can listen for in `native` side for URL etc.

Comment: For short deadlines and low budgets reasons, I've added a check on the `Plaform`: if it's `android` or `ios`, instead of downloading as showed above, I simply open an external browser window that downloads the file from the browser

Comment: that's a nice way too!

Comment: @Deadpool, I just fell on your comment (I'm having the same issue) Is there any chance you still have the solution how you opened an internal file in an external browser to download ? Thanks

Comment: Hi @DanyY sorry if I'm late but I'm not using SO a lot in these months. By the way, unfortunately I changed my job last year and I don't have access to my old projects no more. If I remind correctly, I did it with a GET on server side that returns the file to download and on client side I simply used a `window.open('api url that returns file' + fileId, '_blank');` with the `'_blank'` overload that should open the file in a new window. I don't remember if I used the default window or if I've imported it from cordova. I'm sorry but I hope this could somewhat help you, let me know if it works